# AWS Cloudformation : Private Network : userdata not working : no output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

Hi I have written following template for an Instance resource for Amazon cloudformation. following code is working when I declare **"AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true"** but when I declare same property with **False** eg **"AssociatePublicIpAddress": "false"**. user data is not working. Attached is the code. Any advice on this would be good.

```
"InstanceABC": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Metadata": {
   "Comment": "Install prepration for CloudWatch Log Agent",
   "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
    "config": {
      "files": {
          "/var/log/abccw.conf": {
            "content": {"Fn::Join": ["",[
                        "[general]\n",
                        "state_file= /var/awslogs/agent-state\n",
                        "[/var/log/cfcw.log]\n",
                        "file = /var/log/cfcw.log\n",
                        "log_group_name = ",{"Ref": "CloudWatchLogGroupProtectV"},"\n",
                        "log_stream_name = ProtectVLog\n",
                        "datetime_format = %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S"
            ]]},
            "mode": "000400",
            "owner": "root",
            "group": "root"
                  },
          "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf": {
            "content": {"Fn::Join": ["",[
                        "[main]\n",
                        "stack=",{"Ref": "AWS::StackId"},"\n",
                        "region=",{"Ref": "AWS::Region"},"\n"
            ]]},
            "mode": "000400",
            "owner": "root",
            "group": "root"
          },
          "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf": {"content": {"Fn::Join": ["",[
                                                                               "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                                                                               "triggers=post.update\n",
                                                                               "path=Resources.InstanceABC.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                                                                               "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ",{"Ref": "AWS::StackId"}," -r InstanceABC "," --region     ",{"Ref": "AWS::Region"},"\n",
                                                                               "runas=root\n"
          ]]}}
   }}}
  },
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId": {"Ref": "someImageID"},
    "InstanceType": {"Ref": "someInstanceType"},
    "KeyName": {"Ref": "someKeyPairName"},
    "IamInstanceProfile": {"Ref": "IAMProfilesome"},
    "DisableApiTermination": "False",
    "Tags": [{"Key": "Name","Value": "ABCInstance"}],
    "NetworkInterfaces": [{"AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true","DeviceIndex": "0","DeleteOnTermination": "true","SubnetId": {"Ref": "SomeSubnet"},"GroupSet": [{"Ref": "SecurityGroupSome"}]}],
    "BlockDeviceMappings": [{"DeviceName": "/dev/xvda","Ebs": {"VolumeType": "gp2","DeleteOnTermination": "false","VolumeSize": "8"}}],
    "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
        "#!/bin/sh \n",
        "# Get the latest CloudFormation package\n",
        "apt-get update\n",
        "apt-get -y install python-setuptools\n",
        "wget -P /root https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
        "mkdir -p /root/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest\n",
        "tar xvfz /root/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz --strip-components=1 -C /root/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest\n",
        "easy_install /root/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest/\n",
        "# Start cfn-init\n",
        "/usr/local/bin/cfn-init -s ",{"Ref": "AWS::StackId"}," -r InstanceABC "," --region ",{"Ref": "AWS::Region"}," || error_exit 'Failed to run cfn-init'\n",
        "# Start up the cfn-hup daemon to listen for changes to the EC2 instance metadata\n",
        "/usr/local/bin/cfn-hup || error_exit 'Failed to start cfn-hup'\n",
        "# Get the CloudWatch Logs agent\n",
        "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py\n",
        "# Install the CloudWatch Logs agent\n",
        "python awslogs-agent-setup.py -n -r ",{"Ref": "AWS::Region"}," -c /var/log/abccw.conf || error_exit 'Failed to run CloudWatch Logs agent setup'\n",
        "# All done so signal success\n",
        "/usr/local/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ","         --stack ",{"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},"         --resource InstanceABC ","         --region ",{"Ref": "AWS::Region"},"\n",
        "echo \"************************************************************\" >> /var/log/cfcw.log \n",
        "echo \"Instance ABC Logs: Start\" >> /var/log/cfcw.log \n",
        "echo \"------------------------------------------------\" >> /var/log/cfcw.log \n",
        "echo \"------------------------------------------------\" >> /var/log/cfcw.log \n",
        "echo \"Instance ABC Logs: End\" >> /var/log/cfcw.log \n",
        "echo \"************************************************************\" >> /var/log/cfcw.log \n",
    ]]}}
  }
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "user data is not working"?  Are you seeing a error message?

Comment: no error message, but script in userdata is not processed when instance is being created in a private environment as I don't see any output neither on the cloudwatch nor in the machine.

Comment: Have you looked at /var/log/cloud-init.log on the instance?

Comment: yes, while looking into cloud-init.log I found my userdata script has been written into /var/lib/cloud/instances/<instance-id>/user-data.txt. it seems ok. as I have also checked same

Comment: When you don't have a public IP, can your instance still access the internet? (Check NAT/VPC permissions if you have any). I notice you are using S3 via HTTPS protocol rather than from the CLI, which could change depending on that setting and cause the script to hang and break.

Answer (score 0):

@Robbie in the comments is on the right track.

The instance cannot connect to the public internet to pull the things you reference in your user data. If you need this to work and you want it to work in a private subnet you need a NAT machine in your VPC that is able to proxy the traffic to/from the internet.

Comment: @Robbie, for a test I have removed https request as well as apt-get request, but no luck, still script isn't executed and no file has been created as /var/log/cfcw.log

Comment: I have figured out a way to solve my problem. Thanks for help.